# Return to MainMenu ViewController which is not the initial ViewController - Xamarin iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin

I am trying to find the best way to return to the `MainMenuViewController` and removing all `ViewController` on the top of it.

I have the following set up.

Login Screen (initial view) -> MainMenu (second view)

Within the app I have a button in all my ViewControllers that return to the MainMenu. Before the addition of the login screen I could achieve that by using

`View.Window.RootViewController.DismissViewController(true, null)`.

I have a logout button as well which should lead me to the Login screen.

Since the addition of the login screen I have struggled to get this functionally right.

I have tried to display the login screen from the mainmenu, the problem with this solution is that you can only present the login screen on `ViewDidAppear` which I think it is a bit too late and you can see the main menu screen in the back.

Maybe I need to rely on unwind segues, but I didn't get that to work at all.

Native iOS answers are welcome as it is easy to port to C#.

Note: I am not using `NavigationViewController`.

Comment: I think that  "am not using NavigationViewController." is the main problem here. Model presentation is designed to show only one controller over another, not a stack of them. To show stack of view controllers and navigate between them you should use "NavigationViewController' or you would stuck with a problems like your current, that could be easely resolved via "NavigationViewController"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after posting my question I finally managed to find an answer for my question.

The solution is to use Unwind segues. I wasn't able to get it to work because I was not assigning a `Identifier` to the segue.

Now I can Unwind to any `ViewController` I wish.